# XDocument XElement.Descendants issue

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a simple issue but I don't know how to fix it.  I have an XML document that looks like this

```
<hotel>
   <rooms>
   </rooms>
   <rates>
      <rooms>
      </rooms>
   </rates>
</hotel>
```

Now, in my code I have the following

```
XElement hotel = xDoc.Descendants("hotel").Single();
XElement rooms = hotel.Descendants("rooms").Single();
```

The last line fails because there are two `rooms` nodes.  What I want `Descendants` to do is give the *immediate* descendants of the current node, not every descendant no matter where it is in the document.  How is this possible?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first `rooms` child element of the `hotel` node, use the `Element` method:

```
XElement rooms = hotel.Element("rooms");
```

Also, if you're really using an `XDocument` then the `hotel` node would be the root, and can be accessed using the `xDoc.Root` property.